# Attempting to stand for the kedusho in the blessings before the shema at Shacharis

Tags: minhag, shacharis-morning-prayer, standing-sitting, kedusha-prayer, bircas-krias-shema

In the section starting "יוצר אור" at Shacharis, there is a kedusho. When it is said, most people are sitting. I have seen some people who raise themselves slightly as if to get out of their seats for the pessukim of the kedusho.

Is there a source for this behaviour?

Comment: I think I have seen sefardim do this though I'm not sure. Which type of shul have you seen this

Comment: Ashkenazi - laymen.

Comment: IIRC, the first "kedushah" is explicitly supposed to be said sitting - it's a statement of the malachim and not our action. The middle one (during ChzHaSha"tz) must be said while standing, since it's the kedusha of klal yisroel, and the last one (during ashrei -uva litzion) may be said either sitting or standing. People who rise a little at the first kedusha do so out of it's connection to the one during shemonah esrei, but I don't think there is any source that says one should do so...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I have also seen that the first "kedushah" is explicitly supposed to be said sitting and therefore worry that the "attempt to stand" is misguided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Shulchan Aruch Harav ([OC 59:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=241)) this behavior would appear to be incorrect:

> וכשעונין קדושה זו בצבור יש לענות בקול רם ויש לומר אותה מיושב ולא שישב אם היה עומד אלא ש**אם היה יושב אין לו לעמוד לקדושה זו כמו לקדושה שבתפלה**
>
> And when saying this *kedusha* in public, it should be answered in a loud voice. He should say it while seated, not that he should sit down if he was standing, but that **if he were sitting he should not stand for this *kedusha* as he would for the *kedusha* in the *Amidah***.